# PHP: Searching in database

Tags: php

I have made an normal form that you can enter a user´s fullname in and choose sex.

Now to the PHP for the searching in the database.

```
$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sex"]);
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $full_name));
        $query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR lastname LIKE '$lastname' AND sex = '$sex'"; 
    $result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result1);
echo $count;
```

If i enter Jenni Jackson (that exists) and choose "male", i still get 1 in $count, but Jenni Jackson is a female, and has female in the sex column.. I tried do echo $sex to see the value of $sex if it really is what you chose in the form, and it is correct.

Comment: *(suggestion)* Consider using the [Improved MySQL Interface](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: i.e. *mysqli* . btw is there a question or you just wnat to show that you some bits of php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis in your query as:

```
WHERE (firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR lastname LIKE '$lastname') AND sex='$sex'";
```

without the parenthesis your query is equivalent to:

```
WHERE firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR (lastname LIKE '$lastname' AND sex='$sex')";
```

and since `firstname` condition matches, the row is returned.

This happens because `AND` is having [`precedence`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) over `OR`

Comment: The firstname works fine, but when I search by only the lastname.. e.g "Jackson" then it returns 0. so the OR doesnt work right?

Comment: Adding parenthesis says that the sex must match and either of firstname or the lastname should match.

Comment: Isn't it useless to use `LIKE` without `%` or `_`? What other purpose can it have ?

Comment: I have problems using %, but this is another question.

Comment: @Codaddict - doubletested too. I get zero results when I only type the lastname. Something must be wrong?

Comment: Oh i found out now why. Its because $lastname is what you write after space. So when i type "Jackson" only it think its a firstname, and there's no firstname with jackson, only lastname. my bad accepted

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some brackets

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
         firstname, 
         lastname, 
         id, 
         user_name, 
         sex, 
         last_access, 
         bostadsort 
     FROM users 
     WHERE 
        (
         firstname LIKE '$firstname' 
         OR lastname LIKE '$lastname'
        ) 
        AND sex = '$sex'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets in your `WHERE` clause so that the database knows which takes precedence  (AND or OR):

```
WHERE (firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR lastname LIKE '$lastname') AND sex = '$sex'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're combining AND and OR conditions in the same WHERE clause

Do you mean

```
(firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR lastname LIKE '$lastname') AND sex = '$sex'
```

or

```
firstname LIKE '$firstname' OR (lastname LIKE '$lastname' AND sex = '$sex')
```

Comment: He means the first one or else he wouldn't be asking this question ;-)

Comment: If I have to ask which of the possibilities is intended, then the SQL parser is going to have to guess as well (except SQL has a precedence rule to make it's guess with)... I rest my case

Comment: I just wanted to *jokingly* point out that you *don't have to ask* because a) SQL has a precedence rule and b) TS is not getting the result he expected... I rest my case

Comment: @captaintokyo - I should probably have added a :) after my comment... I didn't perceive your comment as a criticism, and my own reponse to that was intended jokingly as well